# String with brackets to Array PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, forms

i have a Form in html with names like

```
"deliveryAddress[0][name]"
"deliveryAddress[0][firstName]"
"deliveryAddress[0][street]"
```

Now i have a JS function that makes a Json of this form:

```
var queryString = jq('#idOrderForm');
var returnArray = {};
for ( var i = 0; i < queryString[0].elements.length; i++ ) {
    var e = queryString[0].elements[i];
    returnArray[e.name] = e.value;
}
var json = JSON.stringify(returnArray);
```

The Result of this function is the following json:

```
"{"deliveryAddress[0][salutation]":"2","deliveryAddress[0][title]":"-1","deliveryAddress[0] [lastName]":"lastName","deliveryAddress[0][firstName]":"firstName","addrInput":"-1","deliveryAddress[0][country]":"D","deliveryAddress[0][zipCode]":"12345","deliveryAddress[0][city]":"City","deliveryAddress[0][street]":"Street","deliveryAddress[0][houseNo]":"1""save":"true"}"
```

I send this Json to a PHP Script that receive it and use json_decode. the result is the following:

```
json_decode($aParams['dataArray'], true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)


result = {array} [11]
deliveryAddress[0][salutation] = "2"
deliveryAddress[0][title] = "-1"
deliveryAddress[0][lastName] = "lastName"
deliveryAddress[0][firstName] = "firstName"
addrInput = "-1"
deliveryAddress[0][country] = "D"
deliveryAddress[0][zipCode] = "12345"
deliveryAddress[0][city] = "City"
deliveryAddress[0][street] = "Street"
deliveryAddress[0][houseNo] = "1"
save = "true"
```

What i need is a correct multidimensional array like:

```
result =  {array} [2]
 addrInput = "-1"
 deliveryAddress = {array} [1]
  0 = {array} [9]
   salutation = "2"
   title = "-1"
   lastName = "lastName"
   firstName = "firstName"
   country = "D"
   zipCode = "12345"
   city = "City"
   street = "Street"
   houseNo = "1"
```

I hope you understand my requirement and can help me :)

Comment: Why do you need to turn it into JSON to begin with? Even if you're using AJAX you can submit the form data as-is, without any conversion. I don't see why you would create extra work and problems for yourself like this.

Comment: i dont want to confirm the form, i want to save the actual values in the db.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "confirm the form". But anyway if you send the data to the server in form-data format (without converting it to JSON), you can still save it to the database. You just have to make a small change to the PHP script as well so it accepts normal $_POST data instead of JSON. That should be much easier than messing about with pointless format conversions.

Comment: I do not want to submit the form. I want to submit the current state of the form to the PHP script without submitting the form.

Comment: I assume you're using AJAX for that? You can still use AJAX, but you can send the form data without converting to JSON. That's what I've been saying the whole time. I think you have misunderstood me. I am not suggesting you should submit the form, I'm suggesting you simply send the data in the format it's already in. If you're using jQuery, the [serialize function](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) makes this trivial. If you weren't using jQuery, the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object also makes it very easy.